# ContactsApp.createContact() You do not have permission to perform that action

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I'm the admin for my google suite site. As of 2 weeks ago I keep getting the error "**You do not have permission to perform that action.**" when trying to add any contacts programmatically. I've tried adding apis, removing permissions and reauthorizing, copying and pasting the script into new script files, copying the whole sheets files and nothing works. I've used different emails and names etc. I'm running this from my admin side and it worked fine a couple weeks ago.

This problem only happens with the line `ContactsApp.createContact()` and all other `ContactsApp.` methods work fine. I've tried all the suggestions I can find online and nothing is working.

function testthis(){

```
ContactsApp.createContact('Bob','Burger','testthis@gmail.com');

};
```

Any help or suggestions or troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated on this!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that [this scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes):

```
www.google.com/m8/feeds
```

is added and also make sure your **Contacts API** is enabled in your Google Dev console.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. I've turned API's on and off before but don't understand why I need them. I've read all the documentation on it and it doesn't make sense when the programs usually work without dealing with them. How are they different than just permissions? How are they related to projects and how do I know i'm even looking at the correct project? Basically, What are they and what do they do.

Comment: When I go into my GSuite Admin console I see that Contacts API is enabled. But I know there is another screen with projects. I know I had to turn on a similar API before but it just quit working 2 weeks ago and I didn't change any settings that I know of. Thank you!

Comment: So this problem is fixed. The only thing different is that I switched back to the new google contacts in my admin console. They must have stopped supporting the old.

Comment: Problem not fixed. it came back. ha Started new API project and enabled the credentials. Fixed for a little bit but then a few days later, after I shared the sheet with a friend it stopped working again.

Comment: Scope is added. It does nothing for this issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem. In my case, the error was originated in the fact that the format of the input data was not correct. For instance, if you are adding to your contacts an email address, check that this field has actually an email format, otherway the script may not perform.

Comment: Doesn't apply to the question, since the asker states that he tried a valid input `testthis@gmail.com`. Maybe you shoudl have posted this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I can not add comments yet, because i am too new to do it. Anyway could you fix the problem?

Comment: I had the same problem again, and I realized that the origin of this was in the fact of having more than 25,000 contacts. I eliminated a few hundred, and it started working again without problems.